# Bootstrap 4 - Remove margin of the div under the navbar when the nav is expanded

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, bootstrap-4

Can someone help with this case, please

I would like to remove margin-top of the div(which has a permanent class my-3 for margin-top 1rem) under the navbar. I would like that margin-top class (my-3) to be active only when the navbar isn't expanded, because when the nav's been expanded there is a gape between it and the div.

```
 <div role="navigation"> </div>
        <div class="container-fluid ">
                <div class="row-9">
                  <div class="col-xl-9 my-3">
                  </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: your choice) {
      .no-margin {
              margin-top: 0px;
       }
}
```

Then use that class on the div you like. If you have put the links to your CSS and bootstrap in the correct order your code will override Bootstraps code

Comment: i would like to remove the my-3 class of the div, when the navbar is exapanded. not permanently :\

Comment: @xx5ko the class is only activated from a specific width, which means if you put min-width: 990px; the class will be activated on screens wider than 990px